# Remove non-existent records from linked table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got this SQL code that works perfectly for adding records from the master table (Project Tracker) to a detail table (Week01).

```
insert into Week01 (UserName, RecNum)
select "JustMe", p.RecNum
from `Project List` p
left join Week01 w on p.RecNum = w.RecNum and w.userName = "JustMe"
where w.RecNum is NULL
```

Now I need to do the reverse. If there are RecNums in Week01 that do not exist in Project Tracker, I want to delete the row from Week01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Week01
WHERE RecNum NOT IN (SELECT RecNum
                     FROM [Project List])
```

Comment: This looks like it should work - perhaps you can provide an explanation for the original poster.